# Centroid and toppling

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, statics, dynamics

A uniform block is in the form of a square ABCD of sides 2 m and a unit thickness. E is a point on AD such that ED = xm. The portion EDC is then removed from the block. What is the maximum value of x such that the block will not topple?

Comment: This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CG of the cut shape should fall inside the base footprint which is, 2- xm.

The CG is $ \dfrac{ \sum A_n* d\bar{x}}{ \sum A} $

Area of square is 2*2= 4 and its dx=2

Area of the triangle cut off is xm*2/2= xm and its dx = 2-xm/2

$ CG_x = \dfrac {4 *2- ( 2-xm/2 ))*xm }{4-xm } \quad$, note we factored the E, thickness, out.

And this cg must be smaller than the base, $2-xm$